# Relation between two tables with an optional third table in between

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I have the following schema and data.

```
--drop table table_c;
--drop table table_b;
--drop table table_a;

create table table_a (
  id    number(3,0)  primary key,
  value varchar2(10)
);

create table table_b (
  id    number(3,0)  primary key,
  a_id  number(3,0)  not null,
  value varchar2(10),
  constraint b_fk1 foreign key (a_id) references table_a(id)
);

create table table_c (
  id    number(3,0)  primary key,
  a_id  number(3,0)  null,
  b_id  number(3,0)  null,
  value varchar2(10),
  constraint c_fk1 foreign key (a_id) references table_a(id),
  constraint c_fk2 foreign key (b_id) references table_b(id)
);

-- table a
insert into table_a (id, value) values (1, 'a');
insert into table_a (id, value) values (2, 'b');
-- table b
insert into table_b (id, a_id, value) values (1, 1, 'aa');
insert into table_b (id, a_id, value) values (2, 2, 'bb');
-- table c with ref to a
insert into table_c (id, a_id, value) values (1, 1, 'aaa');
insert into table_c (id, a_id, value) values (2, 2, 'bbb');
-- table c with ref to b
insert into table_c (id, b_id, value) values (3, 1, 'ccc');
insert into table_c (id, b_id, value) values (4, 2, 'ddd');
COMMIT;
```

It's basically a relation between `table_a` and `table_c` with a route through `table_b` if we don't have a direct link from `table_c` to `table_a`.

Each element in `table_c` will have either `a_id` or `b_id` filled. If we have `a_id`, we don't have `b_id`. If we have `b_id`, we don't have `a_id`. Both cannot be `null` at the same time, or non-null at the same time.

Now I'm asked to create a materialized view that shows the relation between `table_a` and `table_c`.

My first idea was to update `table_c` so that `a_id` is always up to date. The customer has a strong grip on the database and forbids me to do so!

```
--drop materialized view mv_d;
--drop materialized view log on table_c;
--drop materialized view log on table_b;
--drop materialized view log on table_a;

create materialized view log on table_a with rowid, sequence;
create materialized view log on table_b with rowid, sequence;
create materialized view log on table_c with rowid, sequence;

create materialized view mv_d
  refresh fast on commit
  enable query rewrite
  as
    select a.value as a_val,
           c.value as c_val,
           a.rowid as a_rowid,
           b.rowid as b_rowid,
           c.rowid as c_rowid
      from table_a a,
           table_b b,
           table_c c
     where (c.a_id is null and c.b_id = b.id and b.a_id = a.id)
        or (c.a_id is not null and c.a_id = a.id);

execute dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( user, 'mv_d' ) ;
```

My problem with this mv is that the result isn't what I expect. Here's what I get. Note that the rowid are abbreviated to show their differences and the actual result, meaning why they are duplicates.

```
select * from mv_d;

-- note, the rowids are for information only, but are abbreviated to only show how they're different.
 a_val | c_val | a_rowid | b_rowid | c_rowid
-------+-------+---------+---------+---------
 a     | aaa   | GAAA    | WAAA    | mAAA
 a     | ccc   | GAAA    | WAAA    | mAAC
 a     | aaa   | GAAA    | WAAB    | mAAA
 b     | bbb   | GAAB    | WAAA    | mAAB
 b     | bbb   | GAAB    | WAAB    | mAAB
 b     | ddd   | GAAB    | WAAB    | mAAD
```

Ideally, I'd get the following result from the `select * from mv_d` (bar the `rowid` columns, ofc).

```
 a_val | c_val 
-------+-------
 a     | aaa   
 a     | ccc   
 b     | bbb   
 b     | ddd
```

How can I get that result in my materialized view?

Note that my actual database has respectively 3 million, 6 million and 1 million records for `table_a`, `table_b`, `table_c`. The actual result with everything filtered exists in a materialized view with roughly 10k records.

Comment: `select distinct a_val, c_val from mv_d`?

Comment: @jarlh With an intermediate mv_d of 100 million records? No, I can't have that. The problem is in the query of the materialized view, not in the query after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select      a.value as a_val
           ,c.value     as c_val
           ,a.rowid     as a_rowid
           ,b.rowid     as b_rowid
           ,c.rowid     as c_rowid

from                    table_a a

            join        (           table_c c

                        left join   table_b b

                        on          c.b_id  = b.id
                        )

            on           a.id = nvl (b.a_id,c.a_id) 

;
```

---

For the materialized view please use this old style code

```
select      a.value as a_val
           ,c.value     as c_val
           ,a.rowid     as a_rowid
           ,b.rowid     as b_rowid
           ,c.rowid     as c_rowid

from        dmarkovitz.table_a a
           ,dmarkovitz.table_b b
           ,dmarkovitz.table_c c

where       c.b_id  = b.id (+)
        and a.id    = nvl (b.a_id,c.a_id) 
;
```

Comment: I'll test, but my DBA insisted that that joins don't work in materialized views...

Comment: Now it works like a charm! Thank you very, very much!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, my pleasure :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkowitz Hmmm... reality calls back... It doesn't work if I add `insert into table_b (id, a_id, value) values (3, 1, 'cc'); COMMIT;`. With this I get 5 results instead of 4. And the 5th is a "duplicate".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128352/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-olivier-gregoire).